# getting png image from java service not working in some browsers

Tags: html, google-chrome

i'm trying to display png image, i'm getting as a byte stream  from java service(spring):

```
byte[] buffer1 = pfmAppFacade.getCheckImage(imageId, isFront);

            List<MediaType> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
            list.add(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG); //image/png
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(); 
            headers.setAccept(list); 
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG); 

            ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = new  ResponseEntity<byte[]>(buffer1, headers, HttpStatus.OK);         
            return responseEntity;
```

The image displayed correctly in firefox and chrome ver 31, But in older chrome, safary and ie9 - i'm getting broken image icon displayed.

```
<img src="http://myserverIP/imgService/123432" />
```

If i trying to download image the file that i get is corrupted.
If anybody can show my some solution - will appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is to add .PNG at the end of url:

```
<img src="http://myserverIP/imgService/123432.png" />
```